# Is there a proven formula for Pisano periods (Fibonacci numbers taken modulo $n$)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers, periodic-functions

I've seen on wikipedia this formula:

$$\pi_k(p^n) = p^{n-1}\pi_k(p) $$

It says that the formula holds *unless p is k-Wall-Sun-Sun prime, or k-Fibonacci-Wieferich prime, that is, $p^2$ divides $F_k(p-1)$ or $F_k(p+1)$.*

I don't know if the statement was proven or not. I've search on the internet but could not found any proof for this.

I'm interested in the case when $p = 2$, that is if $\pi_k(2^n) = 2^{n-1}\pi_k(2) $ was proven or it was just tested with computers. I know that the formula  true, but I need the proof of the formula if it exists, because I want to use the formula in my work.

Comment: First of all you may want to add a "citation needed" at WP

Comment: Do you also need the result only for $k\equiv 1,2\pmod 4$? (After all $2^2\mid F_k(3)$ otherwise)

Comment: Thanks @hagen . Here's the link to wikipedia page: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period). Regarding $k$, I only need the result for $k=1$ and $p=2$.

Comment: I want to know if the equation was proven or not, because on some sites I've seen that it was just tested with computers. So I want to know, if it's a conjecture or maybe it's not and it was proven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a conjecture and the formula was proven. If p is not k-Wall-Sun-Sun prime then the formula holds. There's no known prime number which is a k-Wall-Sun-Sun. Prime numbers till $10^{14}$ were tested with computers. Thus, for p = 2 the formula was proven.